# How to save set of images to photo gallery in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have to save some set of images to photo gallery in one button action.

```
for (j=85; j<100; j++)
       {
           UIImage *saveImage=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",j]];
           UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(saveImage,self,nil,nil);
       }
```

I use the above code.image name starts with 85.png and ends with 100.png.It saves 4 or 5 images afterthat it shows some lines in output window as follows

```
-[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL
```

could anyone fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Call Your Save method after some time delay. The image takes sometime to save in photo gallery. And when you save multiple images continuously then processing overwrites and method of saving image doesn't work.

So, delay at least 0.5 second for each image. I used this in my case see below method...

first declare

```
NSInteger frameCount; 
NSTimer pauseTimer;
```

globally. and make a method name

```
-(void)startTimer;
```

now on your save button click call this method

```
-(void)yourSaveButtonClick:(id)Sender
{
    [self startTimer];
}

-(void)startTimer
{
    frameCount = 85;
pauseTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(myFunctionForSaveToPhoneLibrary) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)myFunctionForSaveToPhoneLibrary
{

UIImage *saveImage=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",frameCount]];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(saveImage,self,nil,nil);

frameCount++;
    if(frameCount>=100)
    {
     [pauseTimer invalidate];
     NSLog(@"Images are saved successfully");
    }
}
```

it will Work ..... Thank You!!

Comment: A good suggestion but dont count on a random delay. There is a callback function that UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() uses to tell you its done. Look it up in the docs.